# Do the Mimamsa Sutras of Jaimini and the Samkhya Sutras of Kapila explicity reject the existence of a creator?

Tags: philosophy, brahman, purva-mimamsa, sankhya

As some of you must be knowing, Hindu philosophy comprises of six schools of thought:

1. Vedanta
2. Mimamsa
3. Samkhya
4. Nyaya
5. Vaisheshika
6. Yoga

Of these, the Mimamsa and Samkhya schools are considered atheistic as they reject the notion of a creator of the universe. My question is whether or not the Mimamsa Sutras of Jaimini (the core text which the Mimamsa school is based on) and the Samkhya Sutras of Kapila (the core text which the Samkhya school is based on)
explicitly rejects the existence of the creator?

P.S. I'm aware that a section of the Mimamsa school and the Samkhya acknowledges the existence of Brahman. However, both schools reject the notion of Brahman being the creator of the universe.

Comment: Your original Q did not mention Kapila and Jaimini.. so someone downvoting a correct answer for that reason is not justified at all..also don't know if u know or not Samkhya karika is based on Kapila's teachings and Mimangsa Paribhasa on Jaimini's teachings.

Answer (score 4):

The SAmkhya KArikA ( as per the most ancient MAthor Vritti) is *Niriswara VAdi*. That means it does not accept the existence of a sole creator Iswara. It actually neither accepts nor rejects.

But, according some others, SAmkhya is *Saiswara VAdi* too. So, I think this depends on the interpretations which may vary.

But the philosophy does talk about a creation. Here, the conscious Purusha is the efficient cause (Nimitta KArana) and the inert Prakriti is the material cause (UpAdAna KArana) for the creation.

And, from their union, like that between a lame and a blind, the whole creation comes to existence.

> Purushasya darsanartham kaivalyArtham tatha pradhAnasya |
>   pangandhavadubhayorapi samyogastatkritah sargah ||
>
> For the Kaivalya (or liberation) of the Purusha and for the Darshana
>   (or Bhoga or enjoyment) of the Prakriti, from the union of the Purusha
>   and the Prakriti, like that between the lame (which is Purusha) and
>   the blind (which is Prakriti), the whole creation (sargah) comes into
>   existence.
>
> **SAmkhya KArikA 21**

And,as already said before, **NO,** the text explicitly does not say anything on whether God exists or not.

Their philosophy, is entirely woven around the 24 Tattvas (25 if we include Purusha) and no talks about a sole creator whatsoever.

UPDATE:

I have the book MimAngsA ParibhAshA. And, i have gone through it cursorily. Like SAmkhya, it too does not explicitly reject the existence of a creator. It does not talk about it actually.

NOTE: SAmkhya KArikA is based on Kapila's teachings only just like MimAngsA ParibhAshA is based on Jaimini's teachings.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for the answer from the Samkhya Sutras of Kapila rather than Samkhya Karika.